# "Welcome to chat" dropdown "click here to dismiss"

Tags: feature-request, chat

This thing is just a nuisance, I've been contemplating installing adblock so I can just remove it every time.

Can we get rid of this box, or at the least, design it in a way that does not cover the top menu bar? Or perhaps make the dismissal target area larger?

[image]

That is all.

Comment: I can't up-vote because of the lack of freehand circles.

Comment: "Click here to remove the notification bar" - seems pretty self explanatory =)  Also, this doesn't show *every time* you enter the chat page, does it?

Comment: @jadarnel27 It seems to at least show when it's unnecessary (like, when you're already logged in, and have more than 20 rep, and have been to chat before...)

Comment: @jadarnel27 Yes. Every time I log into the network I see the bar on each of the chat sites. If I dismiss the bar it is removed until I log out and back in again.

Comment: @TimStone That makes sense.  It does seem a little odd (especially the 20 rep part).

Comment: @jadarnel27 It appears to be related to the domain. For instance: I have to dismiss after login for chat.stackexchange, chat.stackoverflow, and chat.meta.stackoverflow.

Comment: @TheUnicornWhisperer Hope the new screenshot clears up any confusion.

Comment: That is not really a freehand circle but I approve of this because of the nice unobtrusive arrows.

Comment: Any reason this hasn't been fixed? As a >20 rep user, it's pretty annoying to still get this notification.