# Why there is notification though my reputation is more than 20 for chat

Tags: support, chat

My current reputation is 318 today i tried fro the chat on the stackoverflow, when i click on chat link the notification displayed even though my reputation is more than 20.
:([image]

Comment: I got that quite a few times, it usually goes away if you refresh.

Comment: It's displayed because it contains more information than just that, e.g. the link to the FAQ.

Comment: agree but bit confusing...

Answer (score 4):

That one is controlled by a cookie; it isn't related to your reputation, so much as people new to chat (meaning: a very high rep user could still be new to chat). We *could* perhaps improve that, though - perhaps taking any prior chat usage into account.

Comment: (somewhat) related feature request: ["Welcome to chat" dropdown "click here to dismiss"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120835)